# How to handle multiply .git folder in react-native git project with multiply project instance

Tags: android, visual-studio, react-native

I know that i can delete folder but in that way android studio comes with :

```
    VCS root configuration problems
    The directory E:\web_s…MyFirstReactNativeApp is registered as a Git root,
    but no Git repositories were found there.
    E:\web_s…ct-native-holly-grail
```

In github gui client i got `no staged file` (Just one file with double first char of folder_name)
if .git exist in sub diretories...